# Vue 3 Option API with TypeScript: How extends 'this'?

Tags: typescript, vue-component, vuejs3

I need to wrap an existing Javascript component. The code will be (simplifying) as below:

```js
import myComponent from './myComponent');
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    value: [String,Number],
  },
  methods: {
    onMyEvent: function (...args: any[]) {
      this.$emit("myEvent", ...args);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    let comp: myComponent= new myComponent(this.value);
    comp.addEventListener('eventcustom', this.onMyEvent);

    //@ts-ignore
    this.component= comp;
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    //@ts-ignore
    this.component.setProperties(this.value);
  },
  unmounted() {
    //@ts-ignore
    this.component.destroy();
  },
  render() {
    //@ts-ignore
    return this.component.getContent();
  }
});
```

This code is valid but if I compile with Typescript I have to put //@ts-ignore in front of `this.myComponent` because it is not known to the component instance. How in Vue3 can I extend this instance for a member that is not in the State part?

In the same way how I can define methods which are not exposed in 'methods' for example the `onMyEvent` should be a method of the instance (private)

Thanks for your proposition...